# the order of C++ implicit arguments: this and the returned object, which goes first?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, g++, arm

In C++, a member function may have up to 2 implicit arguments: the `this` pointer and the address of the returned object. They precede the explicit arguments, but: ***which one goes first?***

In particular, I'm interested in what happens in Android NDK (gcc-based, ARM).

Example:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  int a,b;
  MyClass(int aa,int bb):a(aa),b(bb){};
  MyClass modif(int da, int db) {return MyClass(a+da,b+db);} //an object is returned
};
```

Comment: Address of *what* "returned object"?

Comment: Can anyone help me to find out why _"the address of the returned object"_ should be useful for a C++ programmer?

Comment: It's a library without source. The C++ functions are visible as C ones.

Comment: To make things clear, when you say "the returned object", do you mean the return value, like when a function does `return something;`? The returns are not passed as an argument, it's not passed at all. In fact, *how* it's handled is not specified at all, but usually it's "returned" in a CPU register that the caller reads. To see the specifics you have to make some simple example, and then examine the generated assembly code.

Comment: Yes, I mean the return value, in the particular case that the return value is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're asking about the calling convention (which registers / where on the stack arguments & return values are stored before branching to a function).

It depends **a lot** on the target ABI and even then it's fairly complicated. For ARMv5/6/7, the [Procedure call standard [pdf]](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) is your bible.

You should really read the whole thing if you actually care, but here are the parts you're interested in:

- A Composite Type not larger than 4 bytes is returned in r0.
- A Composite Type larger than 4 bytes, or whose size cannot be determined statically by both caller and callee, is stored in memory at an address passed as an extra argument when the function was called.

  - If the subroutine is a function that returns a result in memory, then the address for the result is placed 
    in r0 and the NCRN is set to r1.
- If the size in words of the argument is not more than r4 minus NCRN, the argument is copied into 
  core registers, starting at the NCRN

*Also*

- For C++, an implicit `this` parameter is passed as an extra argument that immediately precedes the first user argument.

So in most cases the address of a returned composite value is in `$r0` and the implicit `this` pointer is in `$r1`.

Comment: Checked: the disassembly becomes meaningful if I assume _returned composite value_ = r0 and `this` = r1.

Comment: I have to add that in the section **5.5 Parameter Passing** the rule **A.4** reads: _If the subroutine is a function that returns a result in memory, then the address for the result is placed 
in r0 and the NCRN is set to r1._ When you read it, this explicit mentioning of r0 sounds like a mere failure with better language, but in fact this is what specifies that the result address is in r0.