# Sometimes gcc would put the first argument into R1 register when compiling the C++ code for arm abi?

Tags: android, gcc, assembly, arm

From the ARM to C calling convention, I know that the arguments are passed in order starting from registers r0-r4 and then for other arguments stacks are used. Return values are passed to r0-r1.

But in the libart.so (AndroidM, /system/lib/libart.so, 32bit), there is a method seems like doesn't match the rule.

```
//https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/android-6.0.0_r5/runtime/oat_file.cc
std::unique_ptr<const DexFile> OatFile::OatDexFile::OpenDexFile(std::string* error_msg) const {
    return DexFile::Open(dex_file_pointer_, FileSize(), dex_file_location_,
                       dex_file_location_checksum_, this, error_msg);
}

//https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/android-6.0.0_r5/runtime/dex_file.h
static std::unique_ptr<const DexFile> DexFile::Open(const uint8_t* base, size_t size,
                                             const std::string& location,
                                             uint32_t location_checksum,
                                             const OatDexFile* oat_dex_file,
                                             std::string* error_msg) {
    return OpenMemory(base, size, location, location_checksum, nullptr, oat_dex_file, error_msg);
}
```

The OpenDexfile is a memeber function of the OatDexFile class which is a inner class of OatFile class. So the OpenDexFile has 2 arguments actually, as the first argument is "this".
But in the IDA Pro, the OpenDexFile looks like below:

```
.text:002E9718 var_14          = -0x14
.text:002E9718 var_4           = -4
.text:002E9718
.text:002E9718   STR.W           R4, [SP,#var_14]!
.text:002E971C   MOV             R4, R1   ;<<--After analysing, I can assure that R1 is the "this" pointer
.text:002E971E   LDR             R1, [R1,#0x20] ;<<---dex_file_pointer
.text:002E9720   STRD.W          R5, R6, [SP,#4]
.text:002E9724   ADDS            R3, R4, #4
.text:002E9726   MOV             R5, R0 ;<<---It seems like that r0 is added but not for the "this" pointer
.text:002E9728   STRD.W          R7, LR, [SP,#0xC]
.text:002E972C   LDR.W           LR, [R4,#0x1C]
.text:002E9730   SUB             SP, SP, #0x14
.text:002E9732   MOVS            R7, #0
.text:002E9734   LDR             R6, [R1,#0x20]
.text:002E9736   STRD.W          R4, R2, [SP,#8]  ;<<--R2 represent the arg "error_msg"
.text:002E973A   STRD.W          LR, R7, [SP]
.text:002E973E   MOV             R2, R6
.text:002E9740   BL     DexFile::OpenMemory ;<<---DexFile::Open is a inline function. When executing this instruction, r0 equals r5.
.text:002E9744   MOV             R0, R5;<<--OpenMemory is also a bit weird. It looks like that OpenMemory also adds r0 for the return value, because r0 equals r5 before calling OpenMemory
.text:002E9746   ADD             SP, SP, #0x14
.text:002E9748   LDRD.W          R4, R5, [SP]
.text:002E974C   LDRD.W          R6, R7, [SP,#8]
.text:002E9750   ADD             SP, SP, #0x10
.text:002E9752   LDR.W           PC, [SP+4+var_4],#4
```

I am just wondering if there is a special situation in which "this" pointer would be put into R1 but not R0 and the argments are passed in order starting from registers r1.
I will be appreciated if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf)

> If the subroutine is a function that returns a result in memory, then
>   the address for the result is placed in r0 and the NCRN is set to r1.

```
OpenDexFile
```

is (probably) returning a DexFile object which requires a memory to be put, so that's `r0` and `r1` becomes `this`.

This has been talked about before: [the order of C++ implicit arguments: this and the returned object, which goes first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381779/the-order-of-c-implicit-arguments-this-and-the-returned-object-which-goes-fi)

General note is ARM ABIs are similar to Itanium ABIs. If you have a problem finding source to study after checking ARM ABIs, you can look into that one as well.

Comment: **A Composite Type larger than 4 bytes, or whose size cannot be determined statically by both caller and callee, is stored in memory at an address passed as an extra argument when the function was called.**       I am confused about "or whose size cannot be determined statically by both caller and callee", can you give me a example or a linker for this case? Thank you.

Comment: @jinsheng I would ask tat as a c++ question with relative tag.

Answer (score -3):

Check [arm ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) chapter 5.5

R0: for return value

R1-R3 plus stack: for passing arguments